# How to scale down a texture

Tags: scale

Very new to blender so sorry if this is easy. I want to make the tiles on this plane smaller but I can't figure out how. I read about a mapping node, but can't figure out where to put it. If someone could explain how it works that would be great, thanks!

[image]

Comment: you can either do it with an (Input) Texture Coordinate node > (Vector) Mapping node > Image Texture and tweak the Mapping scale values, or select your plane, switch to Edit mode, select all and in the UV Editor, select the UV and scale it up

Comment: @moonboots thanks, I did the UV method and it was really simple!

Answer (score 1):

You can either do it with an *(Input) Texture Coordinate node > (Vector) Mapping node > Image Texture* and tweak the *Mapping* scale values, or select your plane, switch to *Edit* mode, select all and in the *UV Editor*, select the UV and scale it up.